# Text color Transition is is slower than background-color Transition (with same values for transition in * selector)

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

So I'm working on a project for changing theme of the website and I added a transition on the `*` selector for colors and background-colors so that they change smoothly
but the color of text is changing slower than background color of body !

```js
const html = document.querySelector("html")
lightThemeButton = document.querySelector(".light-theme-button")
darkThemeButton = document.querySelector(".dark-theme-button")

lightThemeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  html.style.colorScheme = "light"
})

darkThemeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  html.style.colorScheme = "dark"
})
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  transition: background-color 250ms ease, color 250ms ease;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Transition</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <section>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa cum
          quia assumenda similique in eveniet porro beatae hic? Saepe, earum?
        </p>
      </section>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem et
        nostrum ab nesciunt iusto dolore inventore expedita eveniet ullam maxime
        a excepturi blanditiis aliquid earum alias ex, saepe est modi.
      </p>
      <div class="theme-button-wraper">
        <button class="light-theme-button">Light</button>
        <button class="dark-theme-button">Dark</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried this also by add two classes with custom properties like `--body-bg: #111` but the text transition is still slower than the transition in background color

Comment: I can't see that the background color is transitioning at all, it seems to change instantly in your snippet. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: nope you are not misunderstanding - actually the background transition is significantly faster than text transition due to some unknow reason so it seems instant !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a higher specificity alternative in your CSS to create a smoother transition. The ***** (all) selector is great for targeting every element on the page but due to your background transition happening to the whole HTML document you need to target the parent before anything else which is why you are seeing a delay of just a few milliseconds. By using **:root** or HTML as your selector you should get the expected result. Run the code snippet below to see if that resolves your issue, hope it helps!

```js
const html = document.querySelector("html")
lightThemeButton = document.querySelector(".light-theme-button")
darkThemeButton = document.querySelector(".dark-theme-button")

lightThemeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  html.style.colorScheme = "light"
})

darkThemeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  html.style.colorScheme = "dark"
})
```

```css
:root {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Transition</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <section>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa cum
          quia assumenda similique in eveniet porro beatae hic? Saepe, earum?
        </p>
      </section>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem et
        nostrum ab nesciunt iusto dolore inventore expedita eveniet ullam maxime
        a excepturi blanditiis aliquid earum alias ex, saepe est modi.
      </p>
      <div class="theme-button-wraper">
        <button class="light-theme-button">Light</button>
        <button class="dark-theme-button">Dark</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Additional documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root

Comment: so I got it and it's helping, but how is it helping .. like .. what is the exact reason for **delay**

Comment: Something strange here - there appears to be absolutely no transitioning at all now. Try changing the transition time to something much longer (I tried 25s). The change is instant. I don't understand why this is a solution to the question.